# Wont insert data into table with one to many realtionship in ORMLite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, ormlite

So it wont insert data in table *Task*, who has a foreign key User.

This is *Task* class:

```
package com.example.gencode.execomtodolist.model;

import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;


@DatabaseTable
public class Task{

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private Long id;

@DatabaseField
private String title;

@DatabaseField
private String description;

@DatabaseField
private boolean done;

@DatabaseField (foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true)
private User user;

public Task(){

}

public Task(User user, String title, String description, boolean done) {
    this.user = user;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.done = done;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return " " + title;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public User getUser() { return user; }

public void setUser(User user) { this.user = user; }

public boolean isDone() { return done; }
}
```

And this is a *User* class:

```
package com.example.gencode.execomtodolist.model;

import com.j256.ormlite.dao.ForeignCollection;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;
import java.util.Collection;

@DatabaseTable
public class User{

@DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
private Long id;

@DatabaseField
private String username;

@DatabaseField
private String password;

@ForeignCollectionField
private ForeignCollection<Task> userTasks;

public User(){

}

public User(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return " " + username + " " + password;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public Collection<Task> getUserTasks() { return userTasks; }

}
```

And when i try this:

```
    private void insertUsers(){
    User user1 = new User("Djavo", "666");
    User user2 = new User("Martel", "123");

    userDao.create(user1);
    userDao.create(user2);

    Task task1 = new Task(user1, "naslov1", "opis232", false);
    Task task2 = new Task(user1, "naslov2", "opis3232", false);

    taskDao.create(task1);
    taskDao.create(task2);

    Log.d("ORMLITEDEMO", "User1 and User2 and Task1 and Task2 CREATED!!!");
}
```

Error happens:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: inserting to database failed: INSERT INTO `task` (`description` ,`user_id` ,`title` ,`done` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

I am a beginner at Android, especially at ORMLite, so please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found out what was a problem.
Because i have changed my Task table in Task class, it was needed to recreate a database, to commit changes.
So what i did was to drop my database, and then create it again.
It works now.